# How can I store locally objects downloaded with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireobjectmapper

I am using a 3rd party framework which uses AF for connecting to the API and the objects returned are subclasses of    `AlamoRecordObject`

I thought about writing an extension so those objects conform to `Codable` which I am familiar with, but I think that people making that framework are much smarter than me and there is surely a way to persist those objects locally.

After all they are first and foremost regular JSONs

[The library I'm using](https://github.com/Daltron/Spartan)

Example of the object

[Track](https://github.com/Daltron/Spartan/blob/master/Spartan/Classes/Track.swift) is a subclass of [SimplifiedTrack](https://github.com/Daltron/Spartan/blob/master/Spartan/Classes/SimplifiedTrack.swift), which is a subclass of [SpartanBaseObject](https://github.com/Daltron/Spartan/blob/master/Spartan/Classes/SpartanBaseObject.swift) which is a subclass of `AlamoRecordObject`

Comment: Have you looked at using Realm to store the data?

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t know about Realm before and after your advice I implemented it in my app, incredible library!